# Ordenar string e number ASC

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Preciso ordenar uma tabela em forma ascendente, porém a coluna alvo possui números (1,2,3,4,5 em formato String) e letras (P,M,G,GG).

Como eu posso fazer uma query que ordene primeiro as strings (G,M,P) em ordem ascendente, e depois ordene os números (1,2,3,4...) ?

Tentei com o `CAST:`

```
SELECT * FROM valor_atributo ORDER BY CAST(valor)
```

Dessa forma ele conseguiu ordenar apenas as strings com os números, porém as strings com letras ele não ordenou corretamente.

Preciso ordenar a coluna (valor) primeiro as strings (G,M,P) e depois os números (1,2,3,4)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar assim:

```
SELECT * FROM valor_atributo ORDER BY valor * 1, valor ASC
```

Veja aqui funcionando: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a7d3e/1)

Foi baseado nessa pergunta, onde tive uma solução para um problema quase idêntico: [how-to-order-mysql-varchar-results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055049/how-to-order-mysql-varchar-results)

Comment: Era o que eu precisava. Obrigado, você poderia explicar melhor sobre o valor * 1?

Comment: sim, quando você executa a operação de um texto * 1, por exemplo `'A' * 1` resulta em zero (0), ou seja, as letras sempre virão antes dos números usando isso no `order by`
pra testar, pode executar isso: `select 'A'*1, 'B'*1, 'z'*1, 1, 2`

Comment: ah, um detalhe que me ocorreu é que, se o numero for negativo irá invaildar essa lógica, dai precisa pegar o valor absoluto sem sinal, então na query precisa usar a função `abs`:  `SELECT * FROM dados ORDER BY abs(valor * 1), valor ASC`